# Counting the characters of a text with multiple lines

Tags: java

There is a text that is like:

```
hi hi
hi hi
hi hi
```

The program is supposed to find 12 characters but it prints 14. I have found a different solution to my question but I didn't understand why this code doesn't work:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Learn {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        // variables
        String inName;
        File input;
        int counter;
        String str;

        // program code
        // #1 How many characters
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter the file name: ");
        inName = scan.nextLine();
        input = new File(inName);
        scan.close();
        scan = new Scanner(input);
        scan.useDelimiter("");
        counter = 0;
        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            str = scan.next();
            if (!str.equals(" ") && !str.equals("\n"))
                counter++;
        }
        System.out.println(counter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe, a linebreak is `\r\n` and not only `\n`? But this could have several different reasons...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New lines can be represented using different Control characters \ Escape sequence. Your code doesn't work properly as it only takes `\n` into account which denotes line feed. Carriage return is represented by `\r`.
You can fix your code by checking for carriage return as well by changing

`if ( !str.equals(" ") && !str.equals("\n") )`

to

`if ( !str.equals(" ") && !str.equals("\n") && !str.equals("\r") )`

This way, you will be handling for both CR and LF control characters. If you are interested in learning more about this, check this Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Answer (score 0):

It's prefer to use `System.lineSeparator()` to declare the line separator because it's different in different os and check the empty string using `.trim()`

Update the condition to the following:

From:

```
if (!str.equals(" ") && !str.equals("\n"))
```

, To:

```
if (!"".equals(str.trim()) && !str.equals(System.lineSeparator()))
```

Comment: I understood why to use System.lineSeparator() but why doesn't the code work when I use !str.equals(" ") instead of !"".equals(str.trim()). When I used !str.equals(" ") the program gave 24.

Comment: It gives and prints 12